# How do I need to write this RegEx to match the given test case? (don't match the ending period)

Tags: javascript, regex

regex:

```
/@([\S]*?(?=\s)(?!\. ))/g
```

given string:

```
'this string has @var.thing.me two strings to be @var. replaced'.replace(/@([\S]*?(?=\s)(?!\. ))/g,function(){return '7';})
```

expected result:

```
'this string has 7 two strings to be 7. replaced'
```

In case you want to make it "better" I'm trying to match [Razor Html Encoded Expressions](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) but mind the case about not matching an ending period followed by a space. The test case above shows that with the second (shorter) `@var`, whereas the first captures as `@var.thing.me`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is not restrictive enough i.e., it captures too much. The last `@var.` (including the dot) in your example string is captured because it is followed by a space (as required by the positive lookahead) which, in addition, is not followed by a dot and a space (as required by the negative lookahead). You can try this pattern:

```
/@([\S]*?)(?=[.]?\s)/g
```

It will match the `@something` substring (which can contain dot characters) both when it is followed by a space (as it happens in the first match of your string) and when it is followed by a dot and a space (as it happens in the second match of your string). Testing it in the chromium browser console it seems to work fine:

```
> 'this string has @var.thing.me two strings to be @var. replaced'.replace(/@([\S]*?)(?=[.]?\s)/g,function(){return '7';})
"this string has 7 two strings to be 7. replaced"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with following regex:

```
var input = 'this string has @var.thing.me two strings to be @var. replaced';
input.replace(/(@[a-z][a-z.]+[a-z])/gi, function(){
  return '7';
});
```

This regex `(@[a-z]([a-z.]+[a-z])*)` matches `@`, then letter (in case there cannot be dot after `@`), then letters or dot and letter again at the end.

`i` modificator allows makes regex case-insensitive.

Comment: This looks good but it doesn't replace short identifiers like `@a` and `@at`. If this is a problem I suggest this regex: `/(@[a-z]([a-z.]+[a-z])*)/`.

Comment: Unfortunately I need more than just a-z support, but I see what you're going after here. Good combo. In fact, I may end up coming back to this, but for now an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@((?!\. )\S)+
```

See it [here at regexr](http://regexr.com?33erg)

This matches a `@` followed by non whitespace characters `\S`. But it matches the next non whitespace only, if it is not a dot followed by a space. This is ensured by the [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!\. )` before the `\S`.